# How does the following snippet code works

Tags: tensorflow, keras

How does a statements like `@keras_export('keras.layers.Dropout')` and similar before a class declaration work?

Comment: fwiw here is the source for [`keras_export`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dec8e0b11f4f87693b67e125e67dfbc68d26c205/tensorflow/python/util/tf_export.py#L258-L411). It is a decorator. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/5666087) for more info on decorators.